# Extracting a specific element from each cell within cell array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a cell array `A` of size `10x10` (say). Each cell in turn contains a `5x20` matrix. I want to select `(i,j)` element from each cell, where `(i,j)` are indices within a loop. I can run 4 `for` loops and easily get the answer. It *may* even be faster as it has been discussed many times that loops could be faster than cellfun, structfun etc.

Still, is there any solution using `cellfun` which I can use in a loop over `(i,j)` and extract `(i,j)` element in each cell? I tried writing a function which will act as handle to `cellfun` but I couldn't access two-leves down i.e. `A{eachCellRow,eachCellCol}(i,j)`.

Example:
If `A={[1 2;5 6], [3 4; 6 7]; [3 4; 6 7], [9 8; 5 6]};`

Then for `i=1, j=1 and i=2, j=1` output should be:

```
B=[1 3; 3 9] and B=[5 6; 6 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CELL2MAT](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) gets all the data from a cell array that consists of numeric data only, into a numeric array. So, that helped us here. For your original problem, try this -

```
celldim_i = 10;
celldim_j = 10;

block_size_i = 5;
block_size_j = 20;

search_i = i; %// Edit to your i
search_j = j; %// Edit to your j

A_mat = cell2mat(A);
out = A_mat(search_i+block_size_i*(0:celldim_i-1),search_j+block_size_j*(0:celldim_j-1))
```

Comment: Thank you. +1. Your solution is really fast. I should avoid `cellfun` if possible. I knew that it is slow but didn't realize it is ~3.5 times slower - 24 secs (@thewaywewalk solution) vs 7 secs (your solution) for 100 runs.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize that cellfun would be so slow!

Answer (score 1):

The easy to use `cellfun` one-liner would be:

```
ii = 2;
jj = 1;
A = {[1 2;5 6], [3 4; 6 7]; [3 4; 6 7], [9 8; 5 6]};

B = cell2mat( cellfun( @(x) x(ii,jj), A, 'uni', 0) )
```

gives:

```
B =

     5     6
     6     5
```

---

Advantage over [Divakar's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192295/2605073): **it works also for inconsistent matrix sizes in `A`.**

And if you want to avoid also the outer loop, another fancy two-liner:

```
dim = [2 2];
[II, JJ] = meshgrid( 1:dim(1), 1:dim(2) );

C = cellfun( @(y) ...
    { cell2mat( cellfun( @(x) x( real(y), imag(y) ), A, 'uni', 0) ) },...
      num2cell( II(:)+1i*JJ(:) ))
```

gives:

```
>> celldisp(C)

C{1} =            % ii = 1 , jj = 1

     1     3
     3     9



C{2} =            % ii = 1 , jj = 2

     2     4
     4     8



C{3} =            % ii = 2 , jj = 1

     5     6
     6     5



C{4} =            % ii = 2 , jj = 2

     6     7
     7     6
```

Comment: Solution without `cellfun` indeed is very fast. See my comment to the accepted answer. Thank you for providing solution with `cellfun` as I had mentioned in the question.

Comment: possible. Look at my edit if you want to avoid the loop completely. Won't be faster though.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not an issue, you can concat all matrices along a third dim; and then indexing is very easy:

```
%// Example data
A = {[1 2;5 6], [3 4; 6 7]; [3 4; 6 7], [9 8; 5 6]};
ii = 2;
jj = 1;

%// Compute the result B
A2 = cat(3,A{:}); %// concat along third dim
B = reshape(A2(ii,jj,:),size(A{1})); %// index A2 and reshape
```